# Do hugepages guarantee a single tlb entry in the kernel driver when allocated with alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_COMP)?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, tlb, huge-pages

On a `5.19` linux kernel with transparent hugepages enabled (`/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` set to "always"), I am using the following code to allocate a hugepage in a kernel module:

```
static struct page* allocate_hugepage(void)
{
    struct page *page;

    // Allocate a 2MB hugepage
    page = alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_COMP , 9); //Allocates 2**9=512 pages
    if (!page) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to allocate hugepage\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Map the page to a kernel virtual address
    return page;
}

static int __init lkm_example_init(void)
{
    struct page *hugepage = allocate_hugepage();
    BUG_ON(!hugepage);
    [...]
}
```

This code seems to work -- it gives me 2Mib of physical continuous memory. However, I am not sure whether this page is actually a hugepage in the sense that it only has  one tlb entry (as opposed to 512 entries for all the 4KB pages). How can i confirm that?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113585/how-to-find-the-page-size-associativity-and-tlb-size-and-number-of-entries

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can see this only gives general information about the TLB though, right? Not if a specific page has a 2MB or 512 4KB entries?